# Java: Possible to modify and add statements to ActionListener which has already been defined?

Tags: java, actionlistener, jcombobox

I am trying to modify JComboBox. My class JComBox extends JComboBox. Further, i have implemented ActionListener in JComBox. Now if an object of JComBox is created, say jcb, is it possible to add an action listener to jcb, such that the action performed is what was originally put in the actionPerformed method in JComBox, plus some additional statements?

Comment: Have you tried adding another ActionListener to the JComboBox? If you're only looking to add some additional statements, then that should do the trick.

Comment: If you are asking if it is possible to modify the actionPerformed function outside of the class it is defined in then no it is not possible. If you provided us more information about why you are trying to do this we may be able to provide you with an alternative.

Comment: @Drew - that is what was intended. Main aim - once an ActionListener is implemented by some ClassDemo, is it possible for some subclass of ClassDemo to re-implement ActionListener, but just **add** to the actionPerformed method instead of overriding it? The main aim is to create a class which implements ActionListener (or equivalently, say some KeyListener), but does not prohibit the user, who is going to extend the class, from re-implementing ActionListener, since the user may want to add more statements to the actionPerformed method than the ones that are already written.

Answer (score 0):

Write your function in the subclass like so:

```
public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent e) {
    super.actionPerformed(e);

    // The rest of your code here
}
```

This will run the code in the super class actionPerformed first followed by what ever you put in the method.